# Индекс с enumerate

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import datetime
from Date import Date
import re
index=0
maneDate = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
for index, Date in enumerate(Date):
    if Date[index] < maneDate:
        Date.pop(index)
        with open('Date.py', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            text = f.read()
        with open('Date.py', 'w') as f:
            pattern = re.compile(r'(Date = \[.*?\])')
            new_text = pattern.sub('Date = {}'.format(Date), text)
            f.write(new_text)
        print("Удалил.")
        index+=1
    else:
        print('Всё норм.')
```

Проблема заключается в том, что без enumerate дата в файле Date.py удаляется. Но как только подключаю сюда этот цикл, то он пишет ошибку:

```
Date.pop(index)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

Как исправить ситуацию или какой использовать цикл, чтобы проверял индекс и удалялся, если дата меньше maneDate?

Comment: Вас не смущает, что у вас две разные переменные с одинаковым названием `Date`?

Comment: @andreymal `maneDate` - это сегодняшняя дата, а `Date` - это список и в списке  есть дата. Например, 20.04.19

Comment: Я не про `maneDate`, я про `Date`, прочитайте свой код внимательнее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что Вы создали две переменных с одинаковым названием

```
for index, Date in enumerate(Date):
             ^                 ^
```

Теперь внутри цикла, вызывая

```
Date.pop(index)
```

Вы обращаетесь уже не к списку `Date` а к строке.

Нужно просто изменить названия переменных, например:

```
for index, date in enumerate(Date):
    if Date[index] < maneDate:
         Date.pop(index)
    ...
```